# Why Net.HTTP api not working in Acrobat javascript api?

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat-sdk

I am working on Acrobat javascript api and i am little stuck in one issue when i am trying to do a network connect through `Net.HTTP` api it's says `Net is not defined` but as per the acrobat javascript api docs this is the class mentioned.

Code

```
Net.HTTP.request({ cVerb:"GET", cURL:fURL,  oHandler: ajaxCallback});
```

Please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you run the code in Acrobat or in Reader? As some JavaScript features work only in Acrobat and not in Reader.

Comment: @MihaiIancu Thanks, no i need to run this on chrome browser..

Comment: I don't think that Google Chrome implements the full Acrobat JavaScript specification

Comment: @MihaiIancu Ok so these apis will only works Acrobat but in chrome browser at all??

Comment: Yes, these apis will work for sure in Acrobat. Any other PDF viewer might implement them, fully or partially, or not.

Comment: @MihaiIancu Oh because simple app.launchURL() also not working only what i found app.alert() is working fine...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198486/discussion-between-anshuman1992-and-mihai-iancu).

Comment: You could try the Acrobat plugin: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adobe-acrobat/efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj?hl=en